# How can I avoid the random restart of the xserver?

Tags: 12.04, nvidia, restart, xserver

I'm using a desktop pc with 64bit Ubuntu 12.04 (Kernel 3.2.0-24-generic). Hardware specs are
- Intel Core i7 CPU 860 @ 2,80GHz x 8
- Nvidia GeForce GTS 250
- 750 GB Hard Disk ATA WDC WD7501AALS-00E3A0 (for my /home partition)
- 128 GB Solid-State Disk ATA PLEXTOR PX-128M2S (for all other partitions)

Since I reinstalled the PC with Ubuntu 12.04 the xserver restarts randomly. Most times when I watch a video in the browser (maybe a flash issue?) but sometimes the restart/crash appears when I'm working in an text-editor.

How can I locate the problem? Which information is needed for a useful answer?

Comment: Will you check it's SMPS?? Cause sometimes we can not pay attention to this. Or you can check logs located at # /Var/log

Comment: No idea. I found nothing useful or noticeable in the log files after a crash/restart :-(

Comment: check your memory modules using memtest

Comment: @Alen: I checked my memory with memtest, but their was no error. It's some problem with 12.04. With my previous installation I didn't have this problems :-(

Comment: I had that problem but my problem was overheating, I changed thermal paste and everything was fine. Maybe your problem is overheating too.

Comment: Today I removed the proprietary Nvidia driver from my system and now I'm using the open source driver. I had to search on the internet how to configure my two monitors with xrandr/arandr and set the right primary monitor, but since then my system seems stable now.I will report the status again in the next few days

Comment: OP hasn't signed on in ~2 years and never returned with promised update ~5 years ago. This unanswered 12.04 question is about EOL Ubuntu version and VTC'ing as `not reproducible`.